# Visualforce Controllers: pass parameters from Custom Controller to Standard Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

Could anyone provide me with guidance on how I can pass field parameters from Custom Controller to Standard Controller without the use of URL?

Custom Controller - handles input parameters and database query. Has a button to create New Contact.

Standard Controller - allows for accessing the standard edit page for an object directly.

Goal is to pass the input search parameters from Custom Controller and pre-populate the associated fields on the object's (Contact) Edit page.

This is a resource I have been looking at, but it is used if the button is part of a standard page layout: http://www.interactiveties.com/blog/2016/opportunity-values-via-apex.php

Comment: For SFDC Classic, you have to use URL hacking as mentioned in your link.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but the VF pages I am writing must be comparable with lightning as well. I know I could use one controller for both pages, but I am really trying to utilize the out of the box Contact edit page, instead of creating a VF page replicating the edit Contact page.